# Scroll to comment box Bug on Mobile

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mobile-web

On mobile site, do this: click `add comment` to bring comment text box. Then, tap/click any link on page after scrolling comment box out of screen view.

It'll scroll page up or down to comment box. It doesn't disturb most of times because a new page is loaded instantly (I don't know about slow connection users). But, it becomes annoying when I tap top-right down arrow.. & I need to scroll to top of page to see its output.
Same thing is happened when I long-tap a link to bring options (to bookmark, open in new tab). Its one more reason of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to happen on an iPhone, but of course this bug is old and could have been fixed. On the other hand, moving the screen to the element which has focus seems to be a browser specific behavior.

If you can still reproduce, please give us more insight: what kind of phone are you using, for example?